# Why is the volume data missing in the 15th row of my Pandas DataFrame from Yahoo Finance?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

Apparently Yahoo Finance does have a empty space in the 15th volume spot. I want to make a program that updates every minute and displays the volume in a chart. Is there a way to retrieve all the volume data ? This is the current code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance as yfin

yfin.pdr_override()

now = datetime.now()
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock_name, start=yesterday, end=now, interval="1m").reset_index(
```

This is the console output. Do i have to save the 15th volume and paste it in there if 1min passes ? Or is there a more elegant solution ?

```
195     223359
196     157398
197     158008
198     140398
199     115367
200     125186
201      99746
202     116837
203      78410
204      85128
205     163242
206          0
207     100304
208      72121
209      85434
210     291359
211     160448
212     104333
213     215963
214     144782
215     105991
216     438472
217     256056
218     307365
219     222936
220     201872
```